# C# Printscreen | A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Tags: c#

So I have this form where if the user presses a button, this method gets executed:

```
//Takes a screenshot of the screen to send it with the email
    private void screenshot()
    {
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0, printscreen.Size);

        printscreen.Save(@"C:\Users\*******\Desktop", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

But when I press the button I get the following error:
A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to find out on which line your code crashes?

Comment: The debugger highlights the last line of code, where I try to save the image.

Comment: The path in `Save` is the bottleneck,try to verify the path before using it.

Comment: Try adding a filename after Desktop, e.g. Desktop\MyFile.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bet it crashes calling `Save`, doesn't it? :)

Make absolutely sure it is possible to write to that file!
Like in your case: I hope you're not trying to save the image as your desktop folder, because it kind of looks like it ;)

Comment: Thanks! I changed the last line to: printscreen.Save(@"C:\Users\****\Desktop\File", ImageFormat.Jpeg); And it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's been a pleasure :) I encountered this exception several times and hate how the exception message leaves you without a clue - IOException would make so much more sense...